# Can you safely return null from a custom ValidationRule, to signify no validation performed?

Tags: wpf, null, validationrules, validationrule

I am implementing a custom `ValidationRule` for WPF DataBinding. To do this, I just inherit from `ValidationRule` and implement one or more of a few abstract or virtual methods. This is the method I am implementing:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo, System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase owner)
```

The `ValidationResult` object I am returning must either have `true` or `false` for the `IsValid` property. This logically seems to me to be missing the third option Unknown or Undetermined. In some cases, a validator may not apply.

So what should I return in these cases? Can I safely return `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO!! A validator should not return `null` from any overloads of the `Validate` method, and before you ask it should not throw exceptions either. In either of these cases your application will encounter an unhandled exception in framework code, and probably crash.

So just accept the less than perfect semantics, and return `ValidationResult.ValidResult` if you want your custom validator to essentially be a no-op.

Source: tested on .NET 4.5